# I have an htc blackstone mobile with windows 6.1 professional and want to update windows 7.5

Tags: whatsapp

Nowadays most of apps require windows 7.5 and that's why I want to update windows 7.5 in windows 6.1 professional.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update a Windows Mobile 6 device to Windows Phone 7 OS as this is a completely different system with different hardware requirements.